# Saving data structures in Java

Tags: java

Please give me some advice regarding data saving in Java.

I’m new in Java. Previously I wrote programs on C++.

It was easy to save data in C++: just declare structure, fill its fields and then save it like byte array. As far as Java doesn’t have structures I suppose that Java programming means another save concept.

I will appreciate you for ideas and ideas what to read regarding this.

Comment: Have a look at `Classes`

Comment: And the concept of **serialization**. Please not that in Java you can export your data to file formats like JSON and XML. Anyway I'm voting to close this question as it is really too broad for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler in Java.

Use a `class` in place of your C++ `struct`, and *implement* `java.io.Serializable`. Your IDE will help you build any methods that you need to implement. Conceptually Java uses *reflection* to capture the values of the fields (aside from ones you've marked `Transient`) in your class, so, by and large, the process is automated.

Comment: Great answer on a very broad question.

Comment: Thank for answer! It's really easy to serialize but results are significantly bigger. What I want to ask: is serialization the only Java analogue of structure saving?

Comment: *Serialization* *is* "structure saving", irrespective of the language. Java has a built-in serialization mechanism which is sort-of easy to use, but does not necessarily yield the smallest representation of the data. It is possible to override the default serialization mechanism to represent your objects in literally any way, but it is more work - you need to weigh up the convenience of the default mechanism vs the requirements on the serialized data.

Comment: Also: see Effective Java 2nd Ed Item 74 "Implement Serializable judiciously".

Comment: But given you're new to Java, implement the normal way first before worrying about size, performance, and whatnot.

Comment: Thank you guys! I implemented serialization. But than I thought that there probably is the way to make it in other way.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, by 'saving' you mean saving to a disc.
If that is the case, you should be looking at the concept of serialization in Java.

Make your class implement the Serializable interface.
Then take cue from the following code to serialize.

```
     FileOutputStream fileOut =
     new FileOutputStream("/tmp/employee.ser");
     ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
     out.writeObject(e);
     out.close();
     fileOut.close();
```

Code on similar lines to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

In java instead of structure create a class corresponding to your storage criteria then create object for that class and then you can store the required datas in that object then store that object in array or any collections.

**for eg** create Student class which has name,regno etc.. then create object of student class store the datas in that object,so you can have your data in an object which is similar to structure then you can save students object in array or collections.